# Pinnable Task Pane on Read & Compose Screens has issues

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin

I hope I can get some help on this.  I have a Custom outlook addin

When the addin is pinned on both read and compose. One of the instances of the office-js app I'm running takes control of the taskpane and does not relinquish event handling for the keyboard or mouse.

The problem occurs when  I have both the compose and read addins pinned.

1. Both the Read and Compose version of the addin are pinned.
2. Click on a read email and the addin loads up the email settings.
3. Click fwd on the email. A new compose window displaces the read window and the addin updates its view to the compose version
4. The compose version of the addin is frozen I cannot interact.
5. click back to the read version and close the pinned addin.
6. go back to the draft previously created and the addin now works.

It seems like they're fighting for control of the webview in the taskpane if both are pinned.

Is there a way to force the taskpane to reload to the active instance of the addin.

Hopefully, I explained it correctly.

Comment: Can you please share the platform on which you are seeing this issue?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro
Version 2004
19041.746

Feature Pack 120.2212.5510

Outlook Version 2101
Build 13628.20330

Thank you

Comment: Sorry fogot to add I have implemented and ItemChanged Handler for both.

It basically prints to the subject line to console.log

Comment: Do you have the new Chromium-based Microsoft Edge installed?

Comment: Yes I have the latest and greatest fully updated. 

Microsoft Edge is up to date.
Version 88.0.705.74 (Official build) (64-bit)

Comment: Thanks. From your Office/Outlook version + Microsoft Edge version + Windows version, it appears your underlying browser for add-ins in Outlook should be the new Microsoft Edge. The behavior you are seeing is a known issue when the underlying browser for Outlook add-ins is the old Microsoft Edge. Let's confirm which browser Outlook is using to run add-ins. Simply launch an add-in the taskpane, and then right-click inside the taskpane window / add-in's page. Do you see a context menu containing a number of options including Inspect? Kindly send us a screenshot.

Comment: It's strange I cannot view with the right-click in the taskpane.  For some reason it doesn't work with any addins. 

 I printed console.log(window.navigator.userAgent)

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; WebView/3.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19041

Comment: Got it. The version is for old Microsoft Edge. The change for addins to use the new Microsoft Edge has not been fully rolled out. It appears you are hitting the issue the issue of add-in becoming non-responsive in old Microsoft Edge. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point

Comment: OK thank you for the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received this from the Outlook Addin Team

> Got it. The version is for old Microsoft Edge. The change for addins to use the new Microsoft Edge has not been fully rolled out. It appears you are hitting the issue of add-in becoming non-responsive in old Microsoft Edge. It has been put on our backlog. We, unfortunately, have no timelines to share at this point –

Comment: The issue is fixed in all windows builds 21340 and later. Status on backports to older versions of Windows is still being decided.

Comment: This issue was fixed, and the fix should be available in Windows build 19043.1266 or later. Note that it is the Windows Build that matters, not the Office build.